# All Titles and Menus changed to "CHILD THEME LOADED"

Tags: child-theme

I'm testing out a theme update on our website using a staged site created by WPStaging.  That part seemed to work well.  Then I upgraded the theme, created a child theme from it, and applied that child them to it.  Now the title of every post, page, and even menu is "CHILD THEME LOADED" (see below).  Yet when I edit a page or a post, the correct title is still there (in fact everything about the page or post looks correct in the editor).  Any ideas?

[image: Example]

Comment: It looks like the theme has a bug that filters `the_title` in the event of a child theme being in place. Your best course of action is to contact the theme's author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UUA Theme offers a [starter child theme](https://www.uua.org/communications/websites/wordpress-theme/documentation/technical/child-theme) which consists of an example `style.css` file and `functions.php` file. These files include a few lines of code to test if the child theme is loading correctly.

You need to delete this test code from both files, which is identified in code comments.

Specifically, this code in *functions.php*:

```
/**
 * Below is a test to confirm the parent theme is being overridden by the child.
 * If your page titles say, "Child Theme Loaded," the child theme is working.
 * After you confirm it's working, delete this function and filter.
 */
function uuatheme_title() {
    return "Child Theme Loaded";
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'uuatheme_title' );
```

And this code in *style.css*:

```
/**
 * Below is a test to confirm this stylesheet is being applied.
 * It turns all text to all caps. DELETE this after confirmation.
 */
body {
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
}
```